# Elasticsearch throw Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I have a problem with **Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException:**

I tried **change nest edition(eg:5.xxx,2.xxx,6.xxx)** and can not fixed this problem,I can't found 7.xxx in nuget,so what should I try again to fixed this?

Exception is:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Int64' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'hits.total.value', line 1, position 115.”

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200")).DefaultIndex("my-application");
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        IEnumerable<Person> persons = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person()
            {
                Id = "4",
                Firstname = "aaa",//Boterhuis-040
                Lastname = "Gusto-040",
                Chains = new string[]{ "a","b","c" },
            },
            new Person()
            {
                Id = "5",
                Firstname = "sales@historichousehotels.com",
                Lastname = "t Boterhuis 1",
                Chains = new string[]{ "a","b","c" },
            },
            new Person()
            {
                Id = "6",
                Firstname = "Aberdeen #110",
                Lastname = "sales@historichousehotels.com",
                Chains = new string[]{ "a","b","c" },
            },
            new Person()
            {
                Id = "7",
                Firstname = "Aberdeen #110",
                Lastname = "t Boterhuis 2",
                Chains = new string[]{ "a","b","c" },
            },
             new Person()
            {
                Id = "8",
                Firstname = "Aberdeen #110",
                Lastname = "t Boterhuis 2",
                Chains = new string[]{ "a","b","c" },
            },
        };
        client.IndexMany<Person>(persons, "test");

        var rs = client.Search<Person>(s => s.Index("test"));
        var response = rs.Documents;
```

Comment: If you are using elasticsearch in version 7.x you can install NEST in version alpha using this nuget command `Install-Package NEST -Version 7.0.0-alpha2`. Maybe you don't see it in nuget package manager window because prelease checkbox is not selected.

Comment: @Rob Thank you very much.I resolved this problem with NEST -Version 7.0.0-alpha2.